# What is making Radio button blue vs grey

Tags: html, css

When I visit many webpages I noticed that the standard radio button is blue when selected like this:

[image: Blue radio]

As far as I can tell there is no css changing the look of the radio button to be blue. However When I make a very standard html page it looks like this:

[image: Grey Radio button]

What am I missing exactly? Is it an external library causing the buttons to show blue?

this is the standard radio button code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="color">  Grey 
</body>
</html>
```

I am using chrome version 65 to check

Comment: I've never seen a blue radio button to be honest. Can you provide an example of website that implements it?

Comment: @CristianTraìna when selecting amazon shipping options it is blue radio, another example: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/d/default/

Comment: @CristianTraìna I tried copying the source code exactly the same as the link above and everything is identical except the radio buttons are grey on my server..

Comment: @Sackling CSS. check this : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't reproduce it. Also the css-tricks page shows me gray radio buttons

Comment: By the way, you can inspect the element with Chrome and see the computed style. If a property refers the text `user agent stylesheet` then it's just browser customization.

Comment: Interesting that you cannot reproduce it. I was also using chromes inspector and saw that it was user agent stylesheet which is why I couldn't figure out how they were looking different than the grey.

Comment: another page showing blue radio buttons on my browser: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use UiPath for UI automation and ran into this same problem in Chrome after recent browser updates. It seems Google [changed the default CSS](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/49647088?hl=en) for these inputs in Chrome v83.x plus.

If you would like to change the Chrome browser back to the default gray CSS you can change this new setting in the chrome://flags menu. We had to do this since we rely on some image-based selectors for our UI automation. It would be nice if Google did not force defaults like this.

Here is the answer I used from the link above:

> David Boland 5131 6/16/20
>
> If you must go back to the old (pre v83.x Chrome styling) disable
> chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh (Also called "Web Platform
> Controls updated UI").
>
> I wasn't sure what was wrong with my pages just something didn't seem
> right. I'm going to have to take pictures of the websites I go to
> along with the dates. For me it was an internal LAN gateway config
> page that I knew wouldn't be updated with some weird blue color in CSS
> because it's a really old box.
>
> It changes checkboxes back to the old grey background with black
> checkboxes and gets rid of that weird light blue color everywhere (it
> seems even the hyperlinks got a bit lighter with v83).
>
> I found the flag from a reddit thread. Thanks

Here is a screenshot of that setting:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Styling for these elements is is primarily controlled by the OS/browser, and overrides are not universal across all browsers.  From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio):

> By default, radio buttons (and checkboxes) are styled with the operating system's native styles for those controls. By specifying `appearance: none`, you can remove the native styling altogether, and create your own styles for them.

The rest of this article gives an example of how to style a radio element using the `appearance: none` CSS rule.

Comment: and although `resetting CSS rules` are considered a big no-no - this is actually one of the few exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem,and I found this from google and solved this problem:
Starting in M81, the standard form control elements (e.g. , , ) were given a refreshed look and feel, with improved accessibility and better platform uniformity. This policy restores the old "legacy" form control elements until M84.

If this policy is set to True, the "legacy" form control elements will be used for all sites.

If this policy is set to False or not set, the form control elements will be enabled as they are launched in M81, M82, and M83.

This policy will be removed after Chrome 84.

from:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=UseLegacyFormControls